# Socket cuts the long string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have server.js code

```
var net = require('net');
var queryResults;

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {    
   connection.on('query', function(query) {
      queryResults = queryProcessing(query);
   });
   
   connection.write(queryResults);
   connection.pipe(connection);
});

server.listen(8080, function() { 
   console.log('server is listening');
});
```

as well as client.js code

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(port, host, function(err){
  if(err) throw err;
  client.write(JSON.stringify(Query));
});  
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('Received: ' + data);.
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

The question here is that, sometimes, the results of the user's query will be very long. Socket will cut the string in the middle and report the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

If anyone could provide me some cues, I would be very appreciated.

Comment: Might help to determine if it's always cut at exactly the same point (indicating a potential buffer issue) and how much data is that? Or if it's less predictable and data transfer takes significant time, maybe it's a timeout?

Comment: When using the `net` module, I've found to flush the strings sent I had to add `\n`to the JSON string.